# PHP for HTML forms

Tags: php, html, forms, strcmp, strlen

I have the below drop down list as part of a HTML form:

```
Print Options:<br/><select name="printopts">
              <option selected=""></option>
              <option value="Print Longest Answer">Print Longest Answer</option>
              <option value="Print Sorted Order">Print Sorted Order</option>
              </select>
```

I need my php script to carry out the strlen() function if the user chooses "Print Longest Answer" or strcmp($str1, $str2) if the user chooses "Print Sorted Order".

I understand how the functions work, I'm just not sure where or how to call them in my script. Any help would be super! Cheers!

UPDATE: This is my script/form so far. It begins with some validation checks but I'm trying to work out how to get the strlen() and strcmp() functions for the drop down boxes to execute after these validation checks happen.

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['answer1'], $_POST['answer2'], $_POST['printopts'])) {
  $errors = array () ;

  $answer1 = $_POST['answer1'];
  $answer2 = $_POST['answer2'];
  $printopts = $_POST['printopts'];

  if (empty($answer1) || empty($answer2) || empty($printopts))  {
    $errors[] = 'All fields are required';
    } else {

      if (strlen($answer1) < 4 ) {
          $errors[] = 'Answer 1 is too short! Please Re-enter';
      }
      if (strlen($answer1) > 6 ) {
          $errors[] = 'Answer 1 is too long! Please Re-enter';
      }
      if (strlen($answer2) < 4) {
          $errors[] = 'Answer 2 is too short! Please Re-enter';
      }
      if (strlen($answer2) > 6) {
          $errors[] = 'Answer 2 is too long! Please Re-enter';
      }
      if (is_numeric($answer1)) {
          $errors[] = 'Answer 1 must only contain letters. Please Re-enter';
      }
      if (is_numeric($answer2)) {
          $errors[] = 'Answer 2 must only contain letters. Please Re-enter';
      }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo '<strong>', $error,  '</strong><br/>';
        }
    } 

    else {
          echo 'Thank you for your answers!';
    }
    }


}
?>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
              <p>
              Answer 1:<br/><input type="text" name="answer1"/><br/>
              Answer 2:<br/><input type="text" name="answer2"/><br/>
              Print Options:<br/><select name="printopts">
              <option selected=""></option>
              <option value="Print Longest Answer">Print Longest Answer</option>
              <option value="Print Sorted Order">Print Sorted Order</option>
              </select>
              <br/>
              </p>
              <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
              </form>
```

Comment: Please do a bit of searching before you ask questions here. Examples of this can be found anywhere on the web. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp

Comment: What script?  What have you tried?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Probably just to use numbers instead of strings for the values i.e. `<option value="1">Print Longest Answer</option>`

Comment: Please my friend, other people give some answer but you can do alot by tring for yourself, like many of us.

Comment: I've just added my php script to the original post. I havent added in the functions for the drop down list yet because I don't want them to interfere with the progress i've already made on getting the validation checks to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, first you need to set action='myscript.php' in the <form> html tag and the method parametre (eg.: method='get').
So it is something like this:

```
<form action='myscript.php' method='get'>
...
</form>
```

Then in that myscript.php you will need to have your php code that checks:

```
if($_GET['printopts']=='Print Longest Answer') {
     //do your strlen here
} else {
     //do strcmp here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martina. I'm going to try using that if/else statement with strlen and strcmp after my validation checks. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_print($str1, $str2) {

if ($_GET['printopts'] == "Print Longest Answer") {

   strlen();

} else {

  strcmp($str1,$str2);

}

 }
```

Execute do_print after the form submits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer inversivemedia! i'm gunna trying adjusting my script to work with this. Really appreciated